Row wise operation in data frame
I am working on a data frame, this is my input:
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,3,2],'B':[2,1,1],
              'a':[2,3,1],'b':[1,3,8]})


Expected output:
pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,3,2],'B':[2,1,1],
              'a':[2,3,1],'b':[1,3,8],
             'A*a':[10,9,2],'B*b':[2,3,8],
              'Max':[10,9,8]})


My goal is to multiply columns separately, for example, A*a, B*b. My final variable of interest is "Max", which returns the max of Aa and Bb.
Please note that I have more than two pairs, my real data have dozens of columns, so I need to do this at scale. Ideally I want to structure a function and take a map ({A:a,B:b,C:c...}) as input and run this function on each row of the data frame and return the Max.
I tried this but it did not work out:
dic={'A':'a','B':'b'}


def score(row):
    
    max_score=0
    
    for i,j in dic.items():
        
        if row[i]*row[j]>max_score:
            
            max_score=row[i]*row[j]
    
    return max_score

df.apply(score)



is the map pre defined? or dynamically created?

I editted my question, it should be pre defined.

One option could be to perform a vectorial multiplication:
dic={'A':'a','B':'b'}

# multiply keys/values
tmp = df[list(dic)].mul(df[dic.values()].values)
# update column names
tmp.columns += '*' + pd.Index(dic.values())
# compute max
tmp['max'] = tmp.max(axis=1)

out = df.join(tmp)

Output:
   A  B  a  b  A*a  B*b  max
0  5  2  2  1   10    2   10
1  3  1  3  3    9    3    9
2  2  1  1  8    2    8    8

Another one would be to rename and groupby.prod:
dic={'A':'a','B':'b'}

tmp = (df.rename(columns=dic).add_suffix('_prod')
       .groupby(axis=1, level=0).prod()
      )

out = df.join(tmp.assign(max=tmp.max(axis=1)))

For recent pandas versions:
dic={'A':'a','B':'b'}

tmp = (df.rename(columns=dic).add_suffix('_prod')
       .T.groupby(level=0).prod().T
      )

out = df.join(tmp.assign(max=tmp.max(axis=1)))

Output:
   A  B  a  b  a_prod  b_prod  max
0  5  2  2  1      10       2   10
1  3  1  3  3       9       3    9
2  2  1  1  8       2       8    8


You can do:
d = {"A":"a","B":"b"}
out = pd.DataFrame(
    {k+"*"+v: df[k].mul(df[v]) for k, v in d.items()}
)
out["Max"] = out.max(axis=1)
out = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)

print(out)


   A  B  a  b  A*a  B*b  Max
0  5  2  2  1   10    2   10
1  3  1  3  3    9    3    9
2  2  1  1  8    2    8    8


I propose two options, aptly named option1 and option2.
Option 1 is maybe more readable. You go through all the pairing and create new columns. Then you make a max column and then you return the new df.
def option1(df: pd.DataFrame, d:dict) -> pd.DataFrame:

    new_cols = []
    for i,j in d.items():
        new_col = f'{i}{j}'
        df[new_col] = df[i]*df[j]
        new_cols.append(new_col)

    df['max'] = df[new_cols].to_numpy().max(axis=1)
    return df

Option 2 relies a bit more on numpy, so if your dataset is large, it might be better. It computes all the multiplications at one and does the max right after.
def option2(df: pd.DataFrame, d:dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    i1 = list(d)
    i2 = list(d.values())
    new_data = df[i1].to_numpy()*df[i2].to_numpy()
    max_col = new_data.max(axis=1)
    new_cols = [f'{i}{j}' for i,j in zip(i1,i2)]
    df[new_cols] = new_data
    df['max'] = max_col

    return df


Executing both functions 1000 times here are the timings:
option1: 0.786 s
option2: 0.678 s

So it seems option2 is faster even with this small dataset.

If the pairs are always upper and lower case, this should work:
df.join(
    pd.concat(
        [df[c].mul(df[c.lower()]).rename('{}*{}'.format(c,c.lower())) for c in df.columns if c.isupper()],axis=1)
        .assign(
            Max = lambda x: x.max(axis=1))

Output:
   A  B  a  b  A*a  B*b  Max
0  5  2  2  1   10    2   10
1  3  1  3  3    9    3    9
2  2  1  1  8    2    8    8

